# How to force ATI 5850 to always use 3D clocks?

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking, amd-catalyst

My 5850 graphics card is on its way out and the 2nd monitor output flickers when using low clock speeds, I have however noticed that when gaming or doing anything that forces the clock speeds to ramp up it stops flickering.

How can I force the video card to always use the high speed clock speeds?

I have found this link however it appears to be outdated from 2010 and my CCC does not have those options. I have installed overdrive but I can't find anyway to make it force the 3d clock speeds at all times.
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/276479-33-5770-force-clocks

Comment: Figured it out, found this updated guide that explained how to do it with the new CCC http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=117633